# Spatial Query (Find Points in a Polygon) doesn't return anything when it should

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, polygon, spatial, spatial-query

First time poster! I have a defined closed polygon with a set of coordinates that I drew on google maps and defined in an SQL query. I have a database that contains a shape attribute (I am not sure if it is geometry or geography type but I have kind of tried both).

I am trying to fetch all entries in the database table where the shape is inside the polygon (the latitude and longitude coordinates would be ok too). I get nothing when there are some points inside the polygon and outside the polygon. Running `WHERE @g.STIntersects(Shape) = 0` does not fetch anything either, so I am sure that it isn't a rind orientation problem.

I am running SQL Server 2012. I have tried ST Contains and ST Intersects, and I have also tried taking coordinates raw, adding a new column of geometry points from the latitude and longitude and seeing if those intersect with my polygon but the same issue arises. Various other posts were similar but have not hit the root of my problem.

```
DECLARE @g geometry = geometry::STGeomFromText('polygon ((
-123 45, 
... 
-123 44
-123 45 ))', 4326);

SELECT *
FROM [Database file].[schema name].[table name]
WHERE @g.STIntersects(Shape) = 1
```

I am supposed to get a list of points that are inside the polygon and I get nothing, even though hand checking the coordinates shows that some points are and some points are not in the polygon

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what the issue was: apparently the SRID of the shape files that were in my database was not 4326 but it was some other weird value. Because of that the STIntersects function was returning NULL for everything and not 0 or 1.

I promise that I had spend a lot more time on the problem before posting than the hour it took after my post for me to figure it out on my own.